# ValueError: time data does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' on remote machine file

Tags: python, csv, datetime, remote-access, paramiko

I open a file on remote machine by using sftp and it work fine, but i got this error

```
ValueError: time data '"2015-06-25 14:50:00"' does not match format 
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

but the format i am using is correct. Here is my code to respective portion of code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*
import os
import sys
import time
import stat
import pysftp as sftp
import subprocess
import paramiko
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import mktime, strftime, localtime, sleep



u_name = 'robi'
pswd = 'xxxx'
port = 22
r_ip = 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx'
sec_key = '/home/rob/key_detail'

myconn = paramiko.SSHClient()
myconn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
my_rsa_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(sec_key)
session = myconn.connect(r_ip, username=u_name, password=pswd, port=port,
                         pkey=my_rsa_key)
# print myconn.get_transport().is_active()
# path1 = "/home/rob_remote/sensors/12/tem_data/temp.dat"
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
path1 = "/home/rob_remote/sensors/12/tem_data/temp.dat"
path2 = '/home/new/loc/13/press/pressure.dat'
start_time = datetime.strptime("2015-06-25 14:50:00", fmt)
latest_time = datetime.now()
step_size = 10
diff = latest_time - start_time
minutes_values = diff.total_seconds() / 60
expected = int(minutes_values / step_size)
sftp = myconn.open_sftp()
with sftp.open(path1) as f:
    read = f.readlines()[4:]
    get_values = []
    for line in read:
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        start_date = line[0]
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, fmt)
        current_time = datetime.now()
        step_size = 5
        differ_time = current_time - start_date
        minutes_values = differ_time.total_seconds() / 60
        get_values.append(int(minutes_values / step_size))
    # print 'get_values:::::::::::::::::::', max(get_values)
get_val = max(get_values)
.
.
.
.
```

Can someone help me or guide me to deal with this problem. I would be thankful.

Comment: You have double quotes around the datetime string so you need to strip these out or add them to the format string `'"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'`

Comment: @EdChum Can you give a small example how to add "" to format string. I try 2 solutions but they are not working.

Comment: @EdChum i tried this solution data_tmp = [v.replace("\"", "") for v in start_date], but result in TypeError: must be string, not list

Comment: you should be able to do `start_date= start_date.replace('"','')` and then pass this to your `strptime` using your original fmt string

Comment: try with `v.strip('\"')` to remove double quotes at the beginning and end

Comment: @EdChum I will give it a try and hopefully it will work this time and will come back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your date strings are enclosed in double-quotes, you can either include the double quotes in the format string, or simpler would be to strip these first:

```
In[15]:
d = '"2015-06-25 14:50:00"'.replace('"','')
datetime.strptime(d, fmt)

Out[15]: datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 14, 50)
```

`strip` will also work here:

```
d.strip('\"')
```

So in your code add this

```
start_date = line[0].replace('"','')
```

or

```
start_date = line[0].strip('\"')
```